# Postgresql array of arrays is equal?

Tags: postgresql

I have several tables: things are made from parts. Parts can be of different colors. Every thing has a default color. And if the part is not given a color, then it is inherited from the thing.

```
`colors`
id | color 
 1 | red
 2 | green
 3 | blue

`parts`
id | color_id
 1 | 1
 2 | 
 3 | 2

`things`
id | default_color | name
 1 |       1       | first 
 2 |       2       | second
 3 |       2       | third

`parts_has_things`
id | part_id | thing_id
 1 |    1    |    1
 2 |    2    |    1
 3 |    3    |    1
 4 |    1    |    2
 5 |    2    |    2
 6 |    3    |    2
 7 |    1    |    3
```

And now, knowing what kind of thing I want (details and their colors), I'm trying to find it in the database.

```
SELECT
  things.id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color)
FROM things
JOIN parts_has_things ON parts_has_things.thing_id = things.id
JOIN parts ON parts.id = parts_has_things.part_id
HAVING
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color) @> ARRAY[ARRAY[1,1],ARRAY[2,1],ARRAY[3,2]]::BIGINT[][] AND
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color) <@ ARRAY[ARRAY[1,1],ARRAY[2,1],ARRAY[3,2]]::BIGINT[][]
```

result is:

```
1 | {{1,1}, {2,1}, {3,2}} //i want get only this item
2 | {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,2}}
```

How I can compare an array of arrays here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order your arrays in `ARRAY_AGG`, then you can use `=` to compare them to your ordered array literal:

```
SELECT
  things.id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color)
FROM things
JOIN parts_has_things ON parts_has_things.thing_id = things.id
JOIN parts ON parts.id = parts_has_things.part_id
HAVING
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color)] ORDER BY parts.color_id) = ARRAY[ARRAY[1,1],ARRAY[2,1],ARRAY[3,2]]::BIGINT[][]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions I found -- converting to jsonb

```
SELECT
  things.id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color))
FROM things
JOIN parts_has_things ON parts_has_things.thing_id = things.id
JOIN parts ON parts.id = parts_has_things.part_id
HAVING
array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color)))::jsonb @> array_to_json(ARRAY[ARRAY[1,1],ARRAY[2,1],ARRAY[3,2]])::jsonb AND
array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY[parts.id, coalesce(parts.color_id, things.default_color)))::jsonb <@ array_to_json(ARRAY[ARRAY[1,1],ARRAY[2,1],ARRAY[3,2]])::jsonb
```

UPD: Not working :)